# ListFragment overlap on update

Tags: android, android-listfragment

I try to refresh my CustomListFragment which extends from `ListFragment`in a two pane layout after clicking on a NavigationDrawer with:

```
public void updateInputView(String date)
{
    ArrayList<Custom> values;
    DataSource ds = new DataSource(this.getActivity());

    ds.openReadOnly();
    values = ds.getValues(date);
    ds.close();

    CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this.getActivity(), values);

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

After calling `updateInputView` the second list overlaps the first list, which was created during startup. Now when I choose another one in the NavigationDrawer, the second list disappears and the third list comes up overlapping the first list again.

So what is wrong here?

Edit:

```
private void createView()
{
    String  date;

    if (sDate == null)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }
    else
    {
        date=sDate;
    }

    DataSource ds = new DataSource(this.getActivity());

    ds.openReadOnly();
    values = ds.getValues(date);
    ds.close();

    updateInputView(date);

}
```

This was the code before.

After:

```
public void updateInputView(String date)
{


    DataSource ds = new DataSource(this.getActivity());

    ds.openReadOnly();
    values = ds.getValues(date);
    ds.close();


    this.getActivity().setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+" "+ds.toPrettyDate(date));
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //setListAdapter(adapter);
}


private void createView()
{
    String  date;

    if (sDate == null)
    {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        date = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    }
    else
    {
        date=sDate;
    }

    DataSource ds = new DataSource(this.getActivity());

    ds.openReadOnly();
    values = ds.getValues(date);
    ds.close();

    this.getActivity().setTitle(this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+" "+ds.toPrettyDate(date));    
adapter = new CustomAdapter(this.getActivity(), values);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}
```

Comment: from where createView is called?? it's not Overriden one

Comment: Still I am not getting what is `createView`? what does the class _EXTENDS_ ?

Comment: I mixed it up with `onCreate`. It's called in `onCreate` as one and only method.

Comment: there must be `onCreateView` in `ListFragment`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setListAdapter(adapter);` only once. For updating the list just call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

```
public class Mainactivity extends ListFragment {
    CustomAdapter adapter ;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // Your code .....
       if(adapter ==null){
           adapter = new CustomAdapter(this.getActivity(), values);
           setListAdapter(adapter);
       } 
    }


    public void updateInputView(String date)
    {
        ArrayList<Custom> values;
        DataSource ds = new DataSource(this.getActivity());

        ds.openReadOnly();
        values = ds.getValues(date);
        ds.close();

        if(adapter!=null){
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
   }
}
```

**P.S :** Make sure `onCreateView` is called only once.

Hope it will help you  ツ

Comment: Nope same result. The first list is still in the background

Comment: show me full code.I guess `updateInputView` is called only to  update the List. So the `setListAdapter` line will be in OnCreate

Comment: Updated based on your comment

Comment: are you still getting multiple lists like two then three so on.. ??

Comment: Looks like `onCreate`is called at least twice. I need to figure out why

Comment: I found the problem: Mixed static fragments with dynamic fragments. The static fragment initiated during startup and stays in the background. And after that I worked with dynamic fragments.

Comment: Good.then make sure it is called only once. .